# Can't access function in Angular.js service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to create and use a new service in AngularJS, however, 
I get the following error -

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvKph.png)
ProjectService.one is not a function

The Javascript -

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);

app.service('ProjectService', function () {   
    this.one = function one() {
        console.log('test service');
    };
});

app.controller('ProjectsController', ['$scope', function (ProjectService, Test) {
    ProjectService.one();
}]);
```

Comment: try `this.one = function () {....}`

Comment: that shouldn't matter

Comment: @Bikee Tried anonymous function, but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is something wrong in your controller declaration. Your ProjectService parameter matches the $scope service. Do this instead;

```
app.controller('ProjectsController', ['$scope', 'ProjectService', 'Test', function ($scope, ProjectService, Test) {
    ProjectService.one();
}]);
```

The service-parameters must match the array of services (same number and order)

Comment: Thanks for that. Can't believe I messed that up.
@M.S Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You've to inject the `ProjectService` and other required dependent modules as mentioned below:

```
app.controller('ProjectsController', ['$scope','ProjectService','Test', function ($scope,ProjectService, Test) {
  ProjectService.one();
}]);
```